# Attribute Error when getting unique column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, attributeerror

I am new to Python and Pandas. I am trying to write a function to get a unique list of my column values. My function looks like below, where "placename" is the attribute that I want to get unique values. 'placename' should be passed as a string argument,corresponding to the header of the csv file.

```
def get_city_list(state, type, placename):

     city_dir = os.path.join(baseDir, type + ".csv")
     city_df = pd.read_csv(city_dir, quotechar = '"', skipinitialspace = True, sep = ",") 

     state_df = city_df.loc[city_df["state"] == state] 

     city_list = state_df.placename.unique()

     return city_list
```

However, when I call this function, it throws a attribute error saying 'DataFrame' object has no attribute "placename". It seems that "placename" should not be a string, and when I substitute it as
city_list = state_df.cityname.unique(), it works, where cityname (without " ") is the actual header of the column in the original csv file. Since I want to make my function versatile,I want to find a way to deal with this case so that I dont have to manually change the content of "placename" every time.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: 'cityname','year','state' piRSquared below has solved my problem though, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot operator `.` is reserved to access attributes of an object.  `pandas` is nice enough to make column names accessible via an attribute.  But you can't do something like `df."myplace"`

Change your code to:

```
state_df[placename].unique()
```

This way, you are passing `placename` on to the `getitem` method.

Comment: @macintosh81... if this answer helped you, you should [accept it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)